# How to handle multiple adapters in Spinner's onItemSelected() method in android

Tags: android

Hi am used more than one adapter for spinner. And how to get particular adapter from Spinner's onItemSelected method.  I don't know this is correct or wrong but I need it. Please...
Thanks in advance..